# Text file to array in C

Tags: c, arrays, file, text

Im trying to read a text file and saving the result in a array.

The file has this format:

> DIM: 8   15
>   POPS: 2
>   DIM_POP: 40
>   VIZ: 1
>   FRONTEIRA: 1
>   K: 50  50
>   MOVE: 1
>   NUM_ITER: 50

Im trying to save each value to a int but im having a hard time separating all the values.
My code for now is this:

```
int dim_linha = 0, dim_col = 0, pops = 0, dim_pop = 0, viz = 0, fronteira = 0, k1 = 0, k2 = 0, move = 0, num_iter = 0;

char dimL;
FILE *config;

char buf[100];
char* cfg[90];


//fread(buf, sizeof(char), sizeof(cfg), config);

while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), config) != NULL){
    char *dimL = strtok(buf, "\n");
}

fclose(config);
```

Some stuff are there just for testing. Any tips in how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise to use `mmap()` to just map the entire file into your memory, and then examine the entire file as one large string. That way, you already do away with all the issues related to your fixed size buffer.

Once you have all the data in your virtual address space, you can go over it to determine how much storage you actually need, allocate it, and then parse all the stuff into the allocated storage, knowing that all of it will fit. This eliminates another big bag of issues.

The actual parsing is quite straightforward, just iterate over the `NAME: numbers` combinations parsing them one by one, until you've reached the end.